# SQL change a query to return results for all users

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use sql server and I have the tables:

```
tbl_GroupUser:
user_id, group_id
```

which is a table containing the users and the groups they are in (each group has more than one user_id and each user has more than one group).

```
tbl_group:
id, name

tbl_User:
id, age,....(information about the user)
```

There is a one to many relationship between id of tbl_Group to group_id and between id of tbl_User to user_id.

I created a query returning percentage of groups that has only 2 users in them for a specific user and I want a query that returns the results for all users. This is the query I made:

```
SELECT cast((SELECT count(*) FROM 
(SELECT user_id FROM tbl_GroupUser WHERE group_id in 
(SELECT group_id FROM (SELECT t1.group_id, count(distinct t1.user_id) as numberOfUsers 
FROM tbl_GroupUser as t1 JOIN tbl_GroupUser as t2 ON t1.group_id = t2.group_id group by
t1.group_id) y WHERE y.numberOfUsers = 2)) as x WHERE x.user_id = 'user') as decimal) * 100 /
(SELECT count(*) FROM tbl_GroupUser WHERE user_id = 'user')
```

Which means, count all the groups the user is in that contains 2 users and divide it by the total number of groups the user is in.

An Example of what I want:

tbl_GroupUser:

```
group_id | user_id
------------------
 1       | 1
 1       | 2
 2       | 1
```

The results:

```
user_id | p_Grp2
----------------
 1      | 50.0
 2      | 100.0
```

Comment: use the updated answer and mark as helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple create User define function and use in select query

```
  alter function UDF_GetPercentage(@UserId int)
returns decimal(18,10)
as begin 

declare @Percentage decimal(18,10)
SELECT @Percentage = cast(
(SELECT count(*) FROM 
(SELECT user_id FROM tbl_GroupUser WHERE group_id in 
(SELECT group_id FROM (SELECT t1.group_id, count(distinct t1.user_id) as numberOfUsers 
FROM tbl_GroupUser as t1 JOIN tbl_GroupUser as t2 ON t1.group_id = t2.group_id group by
t1.group_id) y 
WHERE y.numberOfUsers = 2)
)
as x

WHERE x.user_id in (@UserId)
) as decimal)
* 100 
/
(SELECT count(*) FROM tbl_GroupUser WHERE user_id in (@UserId ))

return @Percentage

end
```

and use in select query like this

```
SELECT   user_id, dbo.UDF_GetPercentage(user_id) as p_Grp2
FROM     tbl_GroupUser
group by user_id
```

Comment: I think it works but the results are rounded and not decimal as I wanted.

Comment: not it adds 00 instead of what really supposed to be after the point. For example, instead of 76.11940298507 it shows 76.00

Comment: still int :/ I even changed the -  declare @Percentage int - from int to decimal

Answer (score -1):

Aren't you trying something as simple as this?

```
SELECT user_id, 100.0/COUNT(0) as p_Grp
FROM tbl_User u
INNER JOIN tbl_GroupUser gu ON gu.userId = u.Id
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Comment: I get: Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.

Comment: Have removed all Casts. This is working fine for all work cases.

Comment: What did you calculate? I want the percentage of groups with 2 users the user is in - the # of groups with 2 users the user is in * 100 / the total number of groups the user is in

Answer (score -1):

Count group members on-the-fly with a window function, then aggregate data per user:

```
select user_id, 100.0 * count(case when cnt = 2 then 1 end) / count(*)
from
(
  select 
    user_id,
    count(*) over (partition by group_id) as cnt -- cnt = 2 marks a "two" group
  from tbl_groupuser
)
group by user_id
having count(case when cnt = 2 then 1 end) > 0; -- user in at least one "two" group
```

Comment: When downvoting an answer one should at least leave a comment as to why. I noticed that my query lacked the keyword `case` before `when`. A minor error which was quickly fixed, and apart from that my query is standard SQL and presumably the straight-forward way to approch the problem in SQL Server. Please note that the table is read only once.